# Conduta correta ao realizar e responder uma pergunta

Tags: debate

Como programadores normalmente recorremos ao stackoverflow para sanar algumas dúvidas ou pedir ajuda para um erro que não conseguimos encontrar a solução, porém, entendo que as perguntas da comunidade respeitam regras, se não ficaríamos lotados de perguntas simples que uma simples *googlada* poderia responder. Já fiz algumas perguntas no stack overflow como podem ver no meu perfil, sempre encho a perguntas de informações pertinentes sobre o problema e sempre que esqueço de algo e alguém me solicita por um comentário, sempre coloco, peço desculpas e vida que segue.

Hoje, entretanto, enviei a pergunta **[Setar valor inputmask jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352025/setar-valor-inputmask-jquery)**

Porém, como podem ver pelos comentários da pergunta, acabou se gerando uma discursão um pouco mais acalorada entre mim e este outro usuário.

Não tenho muitos pontos na plataforma e sempre entendi muito bem ao receber feedbacks e tudo mais, entretanto, eu gostaria de saber se eu realmente errei ao ocultar alguma informação se eu realmente levei a essa situação desnecessária.

Obrigado.

Comment: Se é javascript a minha mais sincera opinião é que você deve criar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dá mais trabalho eu sei, que tem de linkar corretamente com os cnd's etc, mas a probabilidade de obter uma resposta, dobra ou triplica porque é muito facil quem quer responder **perceber bem o problema** testando direto na pergunta. E pode ainda copiar o código seguido para a resposta e em meia dúzia de minutos responde. Depois você meteu 1 codigo e 3 imagens mas não explicou o que é cada coisa. Explicar ajuda. No fim pode inclusivamente ...

Comment: ... dizer como está a testar, que valor está a colocar onde e que resultado obtem, e o resultado que pretendia obter e que não está a obter! Não há como ficar mais claro que isso. Quanto mais direto conciso e exato for menos margem dá para interpretação e mais probablidade tem de obter respostas

Comment: Acho que pecou em qualificar um usuário. Como diz em algum lugar que já li nas instruções de conduta do site (desculpe, não vou atrás de mostrar onde isso está escrito), todos aqui estamos para aprender e compartilhar conhecimento, ninguém pode ser julgado melhor que ninguém (dentro do ambiente do site). Atribuir qualidades negativas ou insinuar algo que possa expor um usuário a interpretações negativas sobre a sua moral pessoal fere de modo direto, ao meu ver, o bom relacionamento que o site espera e até impõe aos usuários.

Comment: Bom, como eu sei que o usuário em questão sou eu, vou dar meu parecer: eu realmente não entendi a questão e pedi maiores explicações, porque eu estava pronto a postar uma resposta, mas necessitava de uma informação para tal. Mas de repente recebo comentários pouco amistosos. Quando vi que o senhor estava nervoso, simplesmente decidi me abster e desejar boa sorte. Claro, repliquei alertando sobre uma possível agressividade, que faz parte do processo. Se alguém lhe disser algo do mesmo jeito, vc tb pode e deve, instruir o usuário que ele está ultrapassando os limites. Sem mais e boa sorte.

Comment: Sem falar que quando vc disse "fazer perguntas para pessoas como você" vc está denegrindo não apenas a mim, mas a outros usuários que se enquadram nesse seu "pessoas como você". Como vc não especificou, "pessoas como você" pode parecer algo ruim, e tende a parecer mais pra algum ruim do que pra algo bom, já que não especificou "que tipo de pessoa".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perguntas simples não são problema, algumas das mais simples são as melhores perguntas dos site. Elas ajudam muitas pessoas. O nosso objetivo é que o Google mostre uma resposta nossa como primeiro resultado.

O problema são as perguntas que não ajudam ninguém mais além do autor da pergunta. Mas nem isso é um grande problema. O problema fica grande quando a pergunta é mal formulada e não respeita as regras.

Hoje um dos maiores problema é que a pessoa posta algo que sequer é uma pergunta, portando não poderá ter uma resposta. Não é o caso de falar em interrogação, não é isso (até porque a pessoa faz uma pergunta, em geral é "alguém poderia me ajudar?"). É ser um dúvida específica de forma completa sem firulas. O problema é que nadam postando algo de qualquer jeito e pedindo ajuda. Pedidos de ajuda são fora de escopo aqui. O que fazemos é como se fosse uma prova, você faz uma pergunta e recebe uma resposta. Se precisa ficar discutindo, se precisa de interações, se precisar fazer várias reformulações, se exige interpretação de quem vai responder, não é uma pergunta.

Há casos que nem podemos definir se é uma pergunta ou não, falta tanta informação que não dá para saber o que é aquilo. Não há a menor chance de responder adequadamente. E pior, a pessoa pode estar tão desesperada por uma resposta que é frequente ela aceitar algo que não resolve o problema dela adequadamente, só porque veio alguma coisa. E não é incomum ela perguntar de novo a mesma coisa.

Em muitos casos falta entendimento mínimo da pessoa de como se programa, do que é importante em desenvolvimento de software, de qual é o problema que ela está enfrentando. Ela não tem um problema pontual, ele tem um problema generalizado de desenvolvimento de software e não consegue descrever seu problema.

Há correntes de pensamento de como proceder assim. Eu acho que não tem muito o que fazer. A pessoa precisaria de um curso completo para poder chegar do ponto de fazer uma boa pergunta. E quando digo completo, não é só sobre programação, muitas vezes falta interpretação de texto, lógica básica, entendimento matemático, conhecimento dos termos, dos passos para se realizar determinadas tarefas. É muito complicado colocar o fardo de decifrar o que a pessoa quer nesses termos. Desestimula a participação de bons profissionais que usam seu tempo para ajudar pessoas quem tem problemas específicos em programação, porque ela começa ter que praticamente ser babá da pessoa que pergunta.

Eu não estou entrando no mérito da sua pergunta, estou colocando as coisas de forma geral. O fato é que ninguém mais se interessou pela sua pergunta, um usuário que gosta de responder essas coisas e que não gosta de fechar perguntas e negativa poucas coisas, perdeu a paciência. Novamente não estou julgando se é merecido ou não, não tenho conhecimento específico do assunto para isto.

O que posso afirmar é que mesmo sendo razoavelmente educado você partiu para crítica pessoal desnecessária. A forma como foi escalando foi desnecessária. Seria mais produtivo se tivesse se concentrado no problema da pergunta. Você se irritou, irritou o outro usuário, que não fez nada errado, não violou regra alguma, e não obteve uma resposta. Não digo que fez algo claramente errado, mas podia ter evitado fazer a crítica que fez e tentar entender que havia alguém tentando te ajudar na melhor forma que ela podia. Ela não conseguiu, você não conseguiu resolver o problema da pergunta segundo ela que era a pessoa disposta a te ajudar. Você ficou sem ajuda, não foi bom para todos, até outras pessoas que poderiam se beneficiar de uma resposta para esta pergunta.

Se tivesse feito algo oficialmente errado haveria punição, mas não parece ser o caso.

Acho um exagero também considerar que sua fala poderia ser uma agressão. A forma escrita pode não ter sido muito amistosa, não muito agradável, mas dentro da normalidade.

Apaguei os comentários desnecessários e que não contribui com a pergunta que é o que importa ali.

Infelizmente não sei o que dizer para ajudar mais, para ajudar tornar sua pergunta respondível. Fica só o conselho de se concentrar na pergunta. Por experiência própria começar falar da pessoa descamba e nunca produz bom resultado.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi o seu ponto pelas perguntas, tentarei melhora-las daqui para frente e como o senhor disse, não estou interessado em quem está certo ou errado, apenas que situações como essa não se repitam.